# How to resize DIV element according to browser size?

Tags: html, resize

So here's a project I'm doing for school:

http://graciousevents.co.uk/

The problem is when the browser is re-sized, the photo-gallery moves underneath each other and then the contact DIV gets pushed to the left.

How can I correct this so the contact div doesn't get pushed to the left.

Comment: Looks like you haven't properly closed your tags. Use an "unclosed tag finder" tool such as this: http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using percentages for the sizing? If you give the window a set size and use pixels when sizing everything should stay where it is when you resize the window.

BEFORE:

```
width: 10%;
```

AFTER:

```
width:500px;
```

Answer (score 1):

A particular within the DIV selector, if you want strings to re-size with the browser, instead of pixels, use "em".

Ex.
div{
font-size: x em
}

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS using width: 62.5714%;
    or
Use [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com)